# Will over spray from Ortho Weed-B-Gon Max kill my flowers?

Tags: weed-control, flowers, herbicide

I was spraying some [Ortho Weed-B-Gon Max](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?ds=pr&pq=ortho+weed+b+gon&hl=en&authuser=0&cp=18&gs_id=9&xhr=t&q=ortho+weed+b+gone+max&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&biw=965&bih=581&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=shop&cid=8713941852388440186&sa=X&ei=D7EETq-tMo23twfPmfHLDQ&sqi=2&ved=0CGYQ8wIwAQ)  on my lawn, and some of the mist/over-spray got in and around my flower bed (on flowers).

Are my flowers doomed, or is there still hope that they will live on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of factors - species, amount of exposure, etc. There's a good chance some will survive. Whilst killing ivy with this, I managed to kill the ivy and a small elm tree (the tree should not have had over spray, but perhaps surface roots did) - but cacti and some lawn weeds in the area survived just fine!

If it is a concern then I would try to wash the overspray off the leaves and stems as soon as possible. If it was a few hours ago, it might be too late - I've seen clover respond to the Ortho weedkillers in a matter of hours.